# "parallel" construct not found in EPFL Parallel Programming example

Tags: scala

I'm trying to teach myself some basic Scala programming to execute parallel commutations using the "parallel" construct. I have written the following code trying to add up the sum of two arrays in parallel as an example:

```
object SummingArrays {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var myArray1 : Array[Int] = new Array[Int](100);
    for(i <- 0 until myArray1.length){
      myArray1(i) = 2;
    }
    var myArray2 : Array[Int] = new Array[Int](100);
    for(i <- 0 until myArray2.length){
      myArray2(i) = 5;
    }

    val totalParallel = pSumArrays(myArray1,myArray2)
    println(totalParallel)
  }

  def summi(a: Array[Int]): Int = {
    var sum :Int = 0
    for(i <- 0 until a.length){
      sum = sum + a(i)
    }
    return sum
  }

  def pSumArrays(a1: Array[Int], a2: Array[Int]): Int = {
      val (sum1:Int, sum2:Int) = parallel(summi(a1),summi(a2))

    val tmp :Int = sum1+sum2
    return tmp
  }
}
```

I know its very crude code and I'm aware of alternative methods such as paraSum, but I simply wanted to particularly try the "parallel" construct which is used in a tutorial I am following.

I get the following error message:

```
Error:(31, 32) not found: value parallel
    val (sum1:Int, sum2:Int) = parallel(summi(a1),summi(a2))
```

My first thought was that I am missing an import, but I couldn't find any relevant information on that. I'm using Scala 2.12 and JDK 1.8.

Comment: Which tutorial are you using? `parallel` needs to be defined in scope.

Comment: Hi, its this MOOC: https://courseware.epfl.ch/courses/course-v1:EPFL+parprog1+2018_T1/about

Comment: I suppose by "define in scope" you mean I need to implement a function called "parallel" in the class?

However, in the examle in their videos they never define "parallel" anywhere, my strong impression from the course was this parallel fuction is built in scala. 

Btw, in case you wonder I posted this question in their discussion forum as well but did not get a reply.

Comment: Yeah, or import a function called `parallel`. It isn't a function native to Scala, as far as I'm aware. From looking through the module though, `parallel` doesn't really seem to be doing anything - it just looks like it returns whatever you put in

Comment: ie: `def parallel[A, B](taskA: => A, taskB: => B): (A, B) = (taskA, taskB)`

Comment: This is from lecture 4, right? I just skimmed through the course to try to find the correct part. Let me know if this isn't actually doing what I think it is.

Comment: parallel function is not built into scala. there is `.par` method on collections to make the collection ready for parallel computations like sum, max min etc. The output order of the result is not guarnteed in those computations. The collections with `.par` applied are split into groups, desired operations are performed and elements are combined.. To appreciate the computational advantage the collection usually needs to be fairly large

Comment: The documentation states: "As a general heuristic, speed-ups tend to be noticeable ,when the size of the collection is large, typically several thousand elements".

Comment: Hi James, its actually working.  But from what you say can I assume that it is not actually executed in parallel?